# Adding Label *row number* into the Plot

Tags: r

How Can I modify this code to have a plot so that it shows for
each point on the graph its corresponding row number as a label.

```
inter <- seq(7.5, 21.5, 1)
LogDifference <- c("na",1.5,0.8,0.6,0.01,-0.57,-0.11,0.41,0.068,-0.19,-0.31,0.05,0.14,0.6,0.5)
S<-data.frame(inter,LogDifference)
plot(x = S$inter,S$LogDifference)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that your basic plot is not doing what you want. 
The y values being plotted are the numbers 1 to 14. I think that you wanted 
the numerical values that are in LogDifference.   You can fix this by 
first converting LogDifference to character (it is a factor), then converting 
to numeric. I am just leaving out the "na".

After that, you can use `text` to place labels next to the points. 
The full code is:

```
inter <- seq(7.5, 21.5, 1)
LogDifference <- c("na",1.5,0.8,0.6,0.01,-0.57,-0.11,0.41,0.068,
     -0.19,-0.31,0.05,0.14,0.6,0.5)
S<-data.frame(inter,LogDifference)
plot(x = S$inter[-1], as.numeric(as.character(S$LogDifference[-1])))
text(x=inter[-1]+0.4, y=as.numeric(as.character(LogDifference[-1]))+0.05, labels=2:15)
```

[image: Labeled graph]